# How to retrieve data from a specific child node with the same ID's

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my firebase database looks:
[image]

As you can see above i have 3 Id's in player. The `game_id` is identical  in all three childs. What I want to do know is retrieve `mDisplayName` where the `game_id` is `"-KweUgQj9sV01KvgbCu"`.

This is the code I have now, but It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong and how should I do it?

```
DatabaseReference nishi = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("players");
        nishi.child("-KweUgQj9sV01KvgbCu").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<Object> commentKeys = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    commentKeys.add(childSnapshot.getValue());
                }
                Log.d("Data:", commentKeys.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query your data like this :

```
DatabaseReference nishi = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("players");
    Query query = nishi.orderByChild("game_id").equalTo("-KweUgQj9sV01KvgbCu");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<Object> commentKeys = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    commentKeys.add(childSnapshot.getValue());
                }
                Log.d("Data:", commentKeys.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: This isn't the corect answer. With this code you aren't getting the values of the `name`, you are getting an object of type `Map`, to be more specific a `HashMap` from which you cannot simply get the name. you have marked this answer to be true which is not.

Comment: This answer was just to demonstrate the query to get the DataSnapshot form the specific game_id. Getting name or any attributes from DataSnapshot is depends on developers @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

You should create a User model having variables name, id and points and then write the code as shown below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("players").equalTo("-KweUgQj9sV01KvgbCu").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot s: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = s.getValue(User.class);
            Log.e("Display Name: ", user.getName());
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `equalTo(...)`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("players").equalTo("-KweUgQj9sV01KvgbCu", "game_id")
      .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
             // TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods
             // ...
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this, with your actual database structure so you need to use `denormalization` in order to solve this. This means, that you need change your database structure a little bit, by creating another node called `gameIds`, in which you need to add all the names of all the users under each game id. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- gameIds
          |
           --- -KweUgQj9sV01KvgbCu
                    |
                    --- Users
                          |
                          --- Name1: true
                          |
                          --- Name2: true
                          |
                          --- Name3: true
```

In the end, just attach a listener on this new created node and get all the names from the `dataSnapshot` object that corespond to a particular game id.